# keyboard event has key="Process" on Chromebook

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-events, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm working on a text editor and I'm facing a weird behavior on Chromebooks. When they press a composition key (like ` or ^), I receive a keyDown event with key="Process". This is documented nowhere. It doesn't follow the [specs](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-key), and I couldn't find anything about it on the internet.

The main issue here is that the composition doesn't start after this event, and so the editor prints both the composition key and the letter. Like `^a` instead of `â`. I tested on 2 Chromebooks and got the same result.

What is interesting though is that, if I press the key twice, I correctly get a `Dead` key event, and the composition starts normally.

Does anyone know anything about the meaning of this `Process` key?

Answer (score 2):

"Process" refers to the Input Method Editor (IME). Instructs the IME to process the conversion. The IMA itself is used for input data in some languages (Chinese, Japanese, etc.) Input action is trigger specific Composition Events.

In simple, it opens a window for transferring Latin characters to logographic characters (Japanese for example) by calling the "compositionstart" event.

[Documentation about Composition Events](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-compositionevents)

[Documentation about Common IME keys values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values#ime_and_composition_keys)